# editing after searching in vim

Tags: vim, search, text-editors

if I search from command mode by typing `/something`  I am shown that word in my open buffer, but then I can't delete chars by hitting d or replace with r, these just add more letters to the search term `/somethingd` I can't hit `:` or `a` or `esc` esc throws me back to the top of the buffer.  How can I start editing at the word I just searched for?

Comment: How do you get to the second instance of "something" in a document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you are then in command mode at the place you just found.